# Como hacer un select multiple en django

Tags: django

Buenas noches necesito implementar un select multiple en django y almacenar las opciones seleccionadas en el modelo.

Agradezco por las ideas que me den ya que estoy necesitado de esta funcionalidad.

Comment: Hay un _widget_ para eso, ¿ya consultaste la [documentación oficial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#selectmultiple)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django ya tiene un campo para eso. Lo unico que se hace es definir el widget, por lo que seria algo asi:

```
OPTIONS = (
    ("OP1","Opcion 1"),
    ("OP2","Opcion 2"),
    ("OP3","OPcion 3"),
)

field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=OPTIONS
```

Comment: Es una gran solución. Lo unico malo de esta opción es que cuando grabas las opciones y vuelves a revisar esa instancia creada, no quedan seleccionadas las opciones que has grabado. Estan todas sin seleccionar como si no hubieras seleccionado nada o entraras por primera vez al formulario.